# JAX-RS webservice remove backslash in responce

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

I have build rest api webservice. Which will return json response. The Api returns below JSON with backslash.I want remove those backslash kindly help me.
It prints fine in system.out.println() but if i open in browser it prints with slash.

output:

{\"taskId\":135,\"taskType\":800,\"taskStatus\":0,\"executeCount\":0,\"keyword1\":\"4056563576247\"}
below I have given my code kindly check it.

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

@Component
@Path("services")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class WaybillMonitorResource {`enter code here`

    @GET
    @Path("/statuspoll")
    public Wrapper<?> getbillStatus() {
             JSONArray jsonArrayObj =getJson();
            return WrapMapper.ok().result(jsonArrayObj.toString());

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            this.logger.error("Failed to query the data , taskType illegal"
                    + taskType, e);
            return WrapMapper.illegalArgument();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.logger.error("Query data exception", e);
            return WrapMapper.error();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you create that JSON? Where do you want to remove the backslashes? Client or server side?

Comment: Why do you want to remove backslashes? Even though they may seem verbose, removing them may break your message (For ex., \n will get converted to n .... escaped double backslashes will disappear). If you still want to remove them, anyway, you can use string search/replace OR you can use regular expression matching.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin  I have created JSON using this code.                       JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
            jsonObj.put("taskId", taskCommon.getTaskId());
            jsonObj.put("taskType", taskCommon.getTaskType());
            jsonObj.put("taskStatus", taskCommon.getTaskStatus());                      If print using System.out.println() it works fine. But when i call API in browser responce prints with backslash.

Comment: You should add that JSON create code to the original question so it's easier to read.